# CGGradient not drawing immediately

Tags: ios, objective-c

I really can't understand what's going on. I have gradient on my image view, and i want to remove it when there is no internet. When internet is back, i want to draw it again. That may sound odd, but when internet online and my block called, it (gradient) only drawn after 10-15 seconds. What kind of black magic it is? Here is the code:

```
[[Reachability rac_reachabilitySignal] subscribeNext:^(Reachability *reach) {
        NSLog(@"%hhd reachable internet", reach.isReachable);
        NSLog(@"%hhd reachable waflya", reach.isReachableViaWiFi);

        if (reach.isReachable && reach.isReachableViaWiFi){
            NSLog(@"prepare to insert gradient");
            [_vFooter.layer insertSublayer:self.gradient atIndex:0];
            [self.view setNeedsDisplay];
            [self.newsImage setNeedsDisplay];
        }

    }];
```

Details don't really matter, be sure that block is executed right after connection appeared.

Here is screen when i did breakpoint:

[image]

Comment: You have to perform all UI operations on the main/UI-Thread, currently they are executed in some callback that is probably running in a different thread.

Comment: @luk2302 yeah you right, it solve problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Updates to any UI, including views/layers, must be performed on the main thread!***

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [_vFooter.layer insertSublayer:self.gradient atIndex:0];
    // ...
});
```